# cannot read property props of undefined react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

Currently learning react 'props'. When rendering props inside a component i get an error on compile when passing 'name' and 'age':

"Cannot read property 'name' of undefined."

Here is my code:

Dashboard

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SummaryWidget from '../../Components/SummaryWidgets/SummaryWidget';

class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="animated fadeIn">
        <Row>
          <Col xs="12" sm="6" lg="6">

            <SummaryWidget name='David' age='20'/>


          </Col>

          <Col xs="12" sm="6" lg="6">


          </Col>

        </Row>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Dashboard;
```

SummaryWidget

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SummaryWidget extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render (props) {
    return (
      <div className="SummaryWidget">
      <span>{props.name}{props.age}</span>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default SummaryWidget;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change render method to

```
render () {
    return (
      <div className="SummaryWidget">
      <span>{this.props.name}{this.props.age}</span>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

BTW: If you do not want to do anything in the constructor, you do not have to implement it. Also, if you do not need states and any life cycle method, you should make your component as a stateless component. Like:

```
import React from 'react';

const SummaryWidget = ({ name, age }) => (
  <div className="SummaryWidget">
    <span>{name}{age}</span>
  </div>
);

export default SummaryWidget;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your SummayWidget Component from

```
class SummaryWidget extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render (props) {
    return (
      <div className="SummaryWidget">
      <span>{props.name}{props.age}</span>
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

to

```
class SummaryWidget extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="SummaryWidget">
      <span>{this.props.name}{this.props.age}</span>
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

You do not need to add `render (props)` like this in a class component.

If you need a class component do like above, or if you need a functional component do like @kevin suggested.

[working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kflkhb)